# Serialization QList<MyObject> to JSON

Tags: c++, json, qt, serialization, qlist

I've problem, I tried searched online like convert `QList` to JSON, and send it to URL, but first, I don't found nothing about serialise `QList<Myobject>` to json with Qt and C++.

My not empty `QList`:

```
QList<User> lista;
```

my target is lista to JSON.

How to serialize it? I've saw online that `QJson` exists, but is an external compenent... there is a internal component within Qt 5.9?

Comment: Have you investigated [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/json.html)?

Comment: Yes, maybe don't exist one directly solution from QList to Json, maybe I do conversion Qlist to QJsonDocument...beleive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> an external compenent

[Qt has internal JSON support](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/json.html).

First you need to provide a `QJsonValue` representation for the object itself, and then iterate the list and convert it to e.g. an array. Use `QJsonDocument` to convert it to text:

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/json-serialize-44567345
#include <QtCore>
#include <cstdio>

struct User {
   QString name;
   int age;
   QJsonObject toJson() const {
      return {{"name", name}, {"age", age}};
   }
};

QJsonArray toJson(const QList<User> & list) {
   QJsonArray array;
   for (auto & user : list)
      array.append(user.toJson());
   return array;
}

int main() {
   QList<User> users{{"John Doe", 43}, {"Mary Doe", 44}};
   auto doc = QJsonDocument(toJson(users));
   std::printf("%s", doc.toJson().constData());
}
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "age": 43,
        "name": "John Doe"
    },
    {
        "age": 44,
        "name": "Mary Doe"
    }
]
```

Answer (score -3):

I think a simple solution would be to create the JSON object as a QString. To do so, you can implement `QString User::toJson()`which gives you a JSON-valid string. Then you can iterate on your QList with a foreach :

```
QString finalString ="";

foreach(User user, lista) {
   finalString += user.toJson();
   // Something like that...
}

return finalString;
```